# Hard adjective and conjunction

Tags: перевод

Can someone, Пожалуйста, help me by checking if I have understood the thing with hard adjective and the various forms?

Nom. case: старый журнал

Ack. case: старый журнал

Gen. case: стар-ого журнал

Dat. case: стар-ому журнал

Instr. case: стар-ым журнал

Prepositional Case: стар-ом журнал

Comment: Instrumental is старым. Accusative can be старый or старого depending if it's animate.

Comment: I have updated the question. Would it be wrong to assume that if it is a журнал in this case, the nominative and accusative are identical?

Comment: @Ana No, it's not wrong

Comment: the noun should be declined

Comment: The accusative is correct then, журнал being inanimate; but it should be declined too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change noun ending too:

```
N: старый журнал
A: старый журнал
G: старого журнала
D: старому журналу
I: старым журналом
P: старом журнале
```

The nominative and accusative forms are identical (in this case, not always) by appearance, but they are different by meaning.